# Could someone please help me with string formatting the output of my function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to solve an assignment and I am close to my solution, but here I am not able to understand what is the right way for formatting my output. I tried several times to format but no luck.

I am expecting my output to look like below, when the argument `display_result = True`:

```
  32         1      9999      523
+  8    - 3801    + 9999    -  49
----    ------    ------    -----
  40     -3800     19998      474
```

When `display_result = False` the result would be:

```
   32      3801      45      123
+ 698    -    2    + 43    +  49
-----    ------    ----    -----
```

```
def arithmetic_arranger(problems, display_result= False):
    if len(problems) > 5:
        return "Error: Too many problems."

    first_operand = []
    operator = []
    second_operand = []
    result = []

    for eq in problems:
        eq_splitted = eq.split()


        if not eq_splitted[0].isnumeric():
            return "Error: Numbers must only contain digits."

        if eq_splitted[1] not in ["+", "-"]:
            return "Error: Operator must be '+' or '-'."

        if len(eq_splitted[2]) > 4 or len(eq_splitted[2]) > 4:
            return "Error: Numbers cannot be more than four digits."


        first_operand.append(eq_splitted[0])
        operator.append(eq_splitted[1])
        second_operand.append(eq_splitted[2])
        result.append(eval(eq))

    # string formatting and arrangements in the expected format.
    if not display_result:
        
        first_line = ""
        second_line = ""
        #seperator = ""
        for i in range(len(first_operand)):
            #first_line += """{:>7}\n{}{:>6}\n{}\n{:>7}\n\n""".format(first_operand[i], first[i], second_operand[i], "-"*7, result[i])
            first_line += "{:>6}\t".format(first_operand[i])
            second_line += "{:<2}{:>4}\t".format(operator[i], second_operand[i])
            #seperator = "-"

            arrng = first_line+"\n"+second_line

        print(arrng)
        
    else:
        first_line = ""
        second_line = ""
        #seperator = ""
        fourth_line = ""      # result of the operation of every equation!
        
        for i in range(len(first_operand)):
            #first_line += """{:>7}\n{}{:>6}\n{}\n{:>7}\n\n""".format(first_operand[i], first[i], second_operand[i], "-"*7, result[i])
            first_line += "{:>6}\t".format(first_operand[i])
            second_line += "{:<2}{:>4}\t".format(operator[i], second_operand[i])
            if len(first_operand[i]) >= len(second_operand[i]):
                largest = len(first_operand[i])
                
            else:
                largest = len(second_operand[i])
                
            seperator = "{:>6}".format("-"*largest)

            arrng = first_line+"\n"+second_line+"\n"+seperator

        print(arrng)
        
        




    #print(arranged_problems)



print(arithmetic_arranger(["32 + 6", "1 - 2", "45 + 43", "123 + 2249"], True))
print("\n")
print(arithmetic_arranger(["32 + 8", "1 - 3801", "9999 + 9999", "523 - 49"]))
```

could someone please assist me with the padding and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I remeber that problem from a CV platform or something like that?... Any way I played with your problem and I fount the solution, you will need to add again that restrictions (count of problems, just int and not float value... etc.)

```py
def arithmetic_arranger(problems, display_result=False):
    if len(problems) > 5: return "Error: Too many problems."

    validOperator = ["+", "-"]      # For dynamic updates
    value1st = []
    value2nd = []
    operator = []
    widthNeed = []
    result = []

    for problem in problems:
        problemInfo = f"// Problem number: {problems.index(problem) + 1} -> \"{problem}\""
        rightOperator = False

        # Get out all white spaces before and after the problem content
        ps = problem.strip()
        # Get out all spaces if any and special white spaces
        if " " in problem: ps = ps.replace(" ", "")

        # Search for the valid operators
        for _operator_ in validOperator:
            # If a valid one was found it
            if ps.__contains__(_operator_):
                # Flag it to prevent the outside scope return error message about the operators
                rightOperator = True
                psIndex = ps.split(_operator_)

                # Check for digits and size of the value
                for value in psIndex:
                    if not value.isdigit(): return f"Error: Numbers must only contain digits. {problemInfo}"
                    if len(value) > 4: return f"Error: Numbers cannot be more than four digits. {problemInfo}"

                # If all is good to go, than ad values and operator on their list
                value1st.append(psIndex[0])
                operator.append(_operator_)
                value2nd.append(psIndex[1])

                # Count the of max value size (will be usefully for alignment)
                # The result size can be more that value size so will check an that
                if display_result:
                    result.append(eval(ps))
                    widthNeed.append(len(str(max([eval(ps), int(psIndex[0]), int(psIndex[1])]))))
                # If the result is not wanted to be drawn than check just the values size
                else:
                    widthNeed.append(len(str(max(int(psIndex[0]), int(psIndex[1])))))

        # In case is not the valid accepted operator show and error with the valid ones
        if not rightOperator:
            showValidOperators = ""
            for vOp in validOperator:
                delimiter = ", "
                if vOp == validOperator[len(validOperator) - 1]: delimiter = " or "
                showValidOperators += f"{delimiter}'{vOp}'"
            return f"Error: Operator must be {showValidOperators[2:]}. {problemInfo}"

    # Calculate console render space need it per row
    index = -1; row1st = ""; row2nd = ""; row3rd = ""; row4th = ""; resultOut = ""
    for _ in value1st:
        index += 1
        distance = " " * 4
        align1 = (widthNeed[index] - len(value1st[index])) + 2
        align2 = (widthNeed[index] - len(value2nd[index])) + 1

        row1st += f"{' ' * align1}{value1st[index]}{distance}"
        row2nd += f"{operator[index]}{' ' * align2}{value2nd[index]}{distance}"
        row3rd += f"{'-' * (widthNeed[index] + 2)}{distance}"

        # If the result is wanted than make the math and for the 4th row
        if display_result:
            alignR = (widthNeed[index] - len(str(result[index]))) + 2
            row4th += f"{' ' * alignR}{result[index]}{distance}"

    # Fill "resultOut" with content of the rows
    # And clear unnecessary spaces from the end of the line (that "distance")
    for row in [row1st, row2nd, row3rd, row4th]: resultOut += f"{row.rstrip()}\n"
    return resultOut[:-1]        # - 1 char (which in this case will be the last "\n")

print(arithmetic_arranger(["32 + 6", "1 - 2", "45 - 43", "123 + 2249"], True))
print("\n")
print(arithmetic_arranger(["32 + 8", "1 - 3801", "9999 + 9999", "523 - 49"]))

# DEBUGGING some strange errors founded...
# print(arithmetic_arranger(["1-2", "10+5", "9999 + 9999", " 12 34  - 3 00  ", "\t1+2\n"], True))

# Prevent console to exist until I enter is pressed
# input()
```

I still do not know where is come that **None** text...hmm

The console out view is this[image]

**EDIT**: I added and restrictions checks because was not so hard and fixed that "None" print. **Thx for the comments**

Comment: The None is coming from the `arithmetic_arranger(..)` function - you are printing the return result of it, but it returns nothing, and that function does the printing itself anyway. Simply remove the `print(..)` call around `arithmetic_arranger(...)`

Comment: @ASI "None", that's because the function is doesn't have a return value.

Comment: The `None` is because `arithmetic_arranger` doesn't explicitly return a value, so it automatically returns `None` instead. Then you print that. You should probably have `arithmetic_arranger` return a string but do no printing itself. Or else have it do all the printing and then don't print the function itself.